# wordpress post in category serial number

Tags: wordpress

How can I get a serial number of current post in category?

For ex. I have a category Cars with 4 posts in it. When I open some post I want to see navigation like this: Post 3 of 4 [<<] [>>]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most straightforward way is querying the posts in the category, like this:

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'category_name'          => 'cars',
    'posts_per_page'         => '-1',
    'order'                  => 'DESC',
    'orderby'                => 'date',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then you can get the number of posts with

```
// $query->found_posts gives the number of posts the query has found 
// with the parameters you set
echo $query->found_posts;
```

And you can count up the post you display:

```
$count = 0;

foreach ( $query->posts as $count_post ) {
    $count++;
    // assuming you are inside The Loop
    if ( get_the_ID() == $count_post->ID ) {
        break;
    }
}

// now you can get the "serial number" of the post
echo $count;
```

This might not be the most "WP way" of doing it, but it should work. :)

Comment: Happy to help! :D